# Magento 2.1 - Set customer password in backend

Tags: magento2, customer, security, magento-2.1, password

I want it to be possible for the Magento admin to set the passwords for the customers manually in the backend. Is this not possible anymore in Magento 2?

I can only find the option to reset the password so that an email is generated.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a look and yes, it seems this function was **removed** in Magento 2. There is only the option to reset a password for a customer.

The benefit of this is that the customer will receive an e-mail with a link where they can **set their own password**. There is no need to tell/write the plain-text customer password to an admin.